# How do I pass a Java SQL array to JPA native query as a parameter?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, plsql, eclipselink

I would like to pass an SQL `ARRAY` to Native query as Parameter.

I was able to [pass SQL Array to Stored Procedure](/q/24285545) successfully.

But I can't get the same thing to work with normal native `SELECT` statement.

I am using JPA 2.5, Eclipse Link, Oracle DB.

I want to go for this approach as

1. SQL Statement has limit of 1000 parameters for `IN` clause.
2. JPA Native Query does not support passing `LIST` as a parameter to `NamedNativeQuery`.
3. Using SQL Array it can be directly written in a query as:

   ```
   select * from order
   where customer_id in
            (select column_value from TABLE ( ?param_arr_customer_ids ) )
   ```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Updated the main question